# dictionary with loop (for)

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Please I want to know how python recognizes that **skill** is the key of **mySkills** dictionary.

```
mySkills = {
  "Html": "90%",
  "Css": "60%",
  "PHP": "70%",
  "JS": "80%",
  "Python": "90%",
  "MySQL": "60%"
}


for skill in mySkills:

  # print(skill)

  print(f"My Progress in Lang {skill} Is: {mySkills.get(skill)}")
```

Comment: The default behavior of `dict.__iter__` is to iterate over the keys.  `skill` is a name that *you* have defined to represent each key - you can name it whatever you want.

Comment: Because it's the variable you used in the loop: `for skill in mySkills`, the *name* is irrelevant, you could use `for banana in mySkills: print(mySkills.get(banana))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for skill in mySkills:
```

read this as a `for each skill in mySkills`, it would make more sense.

also, `skill` is a user defined variable.

in this line :

```
print(f"My Progress in Lang {skill} Is: {mySkills.get(skill)}")
```

basically you are saying `My Progress in Lang` for each item of `mySkills` one by one, Is: get the item value.

Comment: On point! for a beginner. ;)